# Error implementing my interface?

Tags: java, interface

im a beginner in java and have been coding for about 4 months now. I was given an assignment where i had to create an interface and a custom class that calls that interface and inside of this interface is a getmethod that calculates carbonfootprints of things. I am at a loss at what to do and have attempted to code some stuff. When i created my interface and tried to implement it, it gave me this error:

`"Project11D is not abstract and does not override abstract method getcarbonfootprint() in carbonfootprint"`

My interface is probably wrong but this is what i have. (It isn't much but i would appreciate any help).

**Interface**

```
public interface CarbonFootprint{
    public abstract double getCarbonFootprint() ;

    }
}
```

**Custom class**

```
public class project11D implements CarbonFootprint {
    public project11D () {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the implementation of getCarbonFootprint() inside your project11D class. Also, you don't have to define the method within the interface as abstract, although I am not sure that it is causing an issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please? Like i said, i'm a beginner and I don't understand much so syntax would be more helpful. thank you.

Comment: Sure. When you implement an interface, all the methods within that interface must be added to the implementing class. So if you have a few methods in project11D 'foo()' and 'bar()', and you are implementing CarbonFootprint, you need to also include all methods within the CarbonFootprint interface (In your case, just the getCarbonFootprint method). Hope that helps

Comment: Oh, Ok alright. I implemented that into my custom class and it worked. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've told Java that project11D implements CarbonFootprint, but you then haven't implemented CarbonFootprint.  According to how you've defined your interface, all implementations of that interface will have a method called "getCarbonFootprint()" that returns a double.  Yet class project11D doesn't have that defined.

Comment: wow. thanks very much man. You have no idea how much that helped me :) Thanks again.

Comment: Um ok, how do i do that? It's my first time asking on this website?

Comment: OH ok i found the check thingy. it said i can accept an answer in 3 minutes so I will do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: There should be an empty check box under the scoring arrows that you can check that means, "hey, this answer is the one that solved my problem."